# How to select index in listbox tkinter PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, selection

I want to select the index I want in the listbox and show it in the listbox. The code below works for this, but it shows the index it chose below. For example, when I call the 50th index, I cannot see if it is selected because the 50th index is below. Is there any way to show this? I'm sorry for my bad english

my code is below:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for item in range(1, 16):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item)

listbox.selection_set(first=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dont add solution to the question, you can either post a new code or delete this question.

Comment: The listbox has a documented methd named  `see` which moves an index into the visible portion of the listbox.

Comment: thanks, this works too, should I use yview or see?

Comment: You should use `see`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it while trying it myself :D it was enough just to add this.

```
listbox.yview (9)
```

new code (SOLVED):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for item in range(1, 30):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item)

listbox.selection_set(first=9)
listbox.yview(9)

root.mainloop()
```